# Pre-select datatable rows when page loads

Tags: jsf, primefaces

```
<p:dataTable var="user" value="#{adminController.users}"  
    selection="#{adminController.selectedUsers}" rowKey="#{user.id}">

  <p:column selectionMode="multiple"/>

  <p:column headerText="Id" width="20px;">  
    <h:outputText value="#{user.id}" />
  </p:column>  

  <p:column headerText="Email" >
    <h:outputText value="#{user.emailId}" />
  </p:column>  
  <f:facet name="footer">
    <p:commandButton value="Disable" actionListener="#{adminController.disableSelectedUsers}"/>
  </f:facet>
</p:dataTable>
```

I am using above code to display data table and selection box so i wanted to select all rows when page render or after doing search '

Comment: why don't you just 'prefill' the `#{adminController.selectedUsers}`?

Comment: thanks for the replay, I tried pre-fill but it is not  cheked

Comment: In my case i don't know the reason,It is not pre-selecting the selection box

Comment: PF version? And please create a [mcve]